# Mid Night club sticker font?

Tags: font-identification

The 80s/90s Japanese street-racing team **Mid Night** car club used a script font on their [windshields](http://speedhunters-wp-production.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/10090053/MidNight-930-08-1200x800.jpg) and bumper stickers.

> *Mid Night*
> CAR SPECIALL

[image: Mid Night CAR SPECIALL]

> http://www.speedhunters.com/2015/10/finding-the-mid-night-racing-930/

What font did the Midnight Club use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Mid Night" is set in [Brush Script](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/brush-script).

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brush_Script
- https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/brush-script

The "CAR SPECIALL" is Helvetica.

[image: Mid Night Brush Script]